# Memory mapped files in .NET app

Tags: memory, file-io

I am using a Memory mapped file to cache a large amount of data for an ASP.NET application.  At the moment I am using the global.asax event to open the file and get a memory mapped file handle which I cache in the application object.  If I dereference that handle to a pointer and try to cache the pointer in my httphandler, I get a protection exception when I reference the pointer so I am caching the handle to the Memory Mapped File and dereferencing it to a pointer inside my httphandler.  This seems to work fine and is pretty quick so I am assuming it is only loading the file into real memory the once.  The problem is that when the load increases I get multiple httphandler instances running at the same time and each one seems to dereference the handle to a different address.  This results in running out of address space pretty quickly.  Short of going to 64 bit, is there some way to force managed code to share a common chunk of memory between threads?  Is there a better way to acomplish what I am trying to do here?

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Comment: Just as an update to this, I did try using C# and unsafe but it crashes at random times with memory protection exceptions.  It would appear that the correct way to deal with this is using the handle and mapping to a pointer everytime you use it.  I overcame the running out of address space issue by only mapping the portion of the file I needed.  As a bonus, this allows the file to grow well beyond the 2GB address space limitations.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could provide the pointer to the memory mapped file from a singleton, right?

Comment: No, as soon as you try to use the pointer in managed code you get a protection violation so the CLR is not happy trusting that memory it doesn't know about is safe to use.  I suppose the next step is to explore the UNSAFE keyword but I was hoping to keep this available to VB programmers.

Comment: If the idea was to keep the handle and derefference it in code protected by the singleton, it would put a severe crick in the scaleablity as I use the memory for most of the process.